# Given positive integers $a,b,n,t$ with $n>t$ and the relations $n-1=a(t-1)$ and $an=bt$, prove that $b>t$.

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Given positive integers $a,b,n,t$ with $n>t$ and the relations $n-1=a(t-1)$ and $an=bt$, prove that $b>t$.
When $n$ is prime, $an=bt$ implies $n\mid b$ or $n\mid t$, so $n\mid b$ since $t<n$, so $b\geq n>t$.
Numeric evidence suggests that it is true in general, but I cannot find a general proof.

Comment: Assume $b<t$ and contradict the relations provided.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$n=a(t-1)+1>t$ so $a>1$.

$bt=an=a(a(t-1)+1)=a^2(t-1)+a$ so $t \mid a^2-a$ and $a^2-a>0$ since $a>1$. Thus $t \leq a^2-a$.

Thus $bt=a^2(t-1)+a \geq (a+t)(t-1)+a=t^2+(a-1)t>t^2$. Thus $b>t$.